# Change sign up fee in cart for subscription products WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, subscription

i am changing the price of products in cart like this

```
   add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_custom_price',1000,1);
    function set_custom_price($cart_obj) {
        foreach ($cart_obj->get_cart() as $key => $value) {

        if($value['alredy_have_number'] == true) {
             $value['data']->set_price(0.90);
        }
      }
   }
```

It works fine for recurring price but I wants to change signup fee for subscription products. what function or hook can I use for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_subscription_signup_fee', 1000, 1 );
function change_subscription_signup_fee( $cart ) {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

        // Check that product custom cart item data "alredy_have_number" exist and is true
        if( isset($cart_item['alredy_have_number']) && $cart_item['alredy_have_number'] ) {


            // Check if subscription products
            if ( in_array( $cart_item['data']->get_type(), ['subscription', 'subscription_variation']) ) {
                // Change subscription Sign up fee
                $cart_item['data']->update_meta_data('_subscription_sign_up_fee', 0.90);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Please note, that not all code is easy to understand for everyone. Please take your time to _explain_ in plain text what your code is doing, which goal it achieves and why it solves the OPs problem. Thanks.

Comment: thanks man... this line saved me $cart_item['data']->update_meta_data('_subscription_sign_up_fee', 3.40);